# Upgrading a treadmill controller / console

Tags: microcontroller, motor

So I have an older model treadmill that I would like to upgrade if possible. The newer treadmills roll to a stop very elegantly, whereas this older model just switches off. Also the console is old, worn out etc. It's a very common brand, EKS Fitness.

Under the hood, I see a motor for speed, and a motor for tilt, and a controller, and then of course the console.

I've asked and been told that the console and controller cannot be replaced.

But I'm skeptical. Surely the Controller and Console together represent 99% of the electronics? The two motors are almost certainly the same across many different models. I don't unfortunately have a whole lot of other parts to try, but if I could simply rewire the motor connections for a new controller/console, I would stand a good chance of success.... no? What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, but isn't clear what you are asking. What exactly is your question? You want to redo all electronics of your old treadmill? That's a considerably complex project, I would say.

Comment: I'm looking for confirmation that two motors plugged into a whole controller / console system, are just that - two motors. If I treat the whole console / controller system as a black box, changing it would actually be quite simple.

Comment: A motor's a motor. As long as the motors are of similar spec (RPM at Voltage, Phases, Pinout), it should work similarly. The other parts that need more consideration are limit switches, and possibly speed feedback monitors (safety features). Everything else should be contained in the console.

Comment: See the first part of http://shdesigns.org/Craftsman-12x36/treadmill.shtml or http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-a-Treadmill-DC-Drive-Motor-and-PWM-Speed-Contr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background:  "Long ago" [it feels] I designed the "downstairs" electronics for several different items of exercise equipment which interfaced to consoles and to various sensors. 
I've done some troubleshooting on treadmills.

What you want to do is potentially possible but the factors identified by @knowhow are relevant and some may make life harder than others. It is reasonably likely but not certain that a manufacturer will use similar motor types between models, but also entirely feasible that they may change suddenly.

Many treadmills use DC motors rated in the "few horsepower" range. There is a reasonable chance that a new controller will drive the motor if both use a DC motor. But, as knowhow notes, if a sensor type has been changed or if a different sense current is fed to a device that is current dependent or ... then there could be trouble.

If you know enough about how such things work you could add some features to your existing controller. eg instead of hitting "turn off" you could trip a circuit which feeds progressive "slow down" signals to the user speed control inputs to achieve smooth slow down to stop. This could be done entirely at the user interface level and not need much knowledge of internal workings.

If functionality is Ok but the console is physically 'deprecated' you could build a gee-whizz looking console and feed signals to the existing board.

As passerby notes - the control of a motor may be easy enough and being able to "talk to" the controller board may be all that is needed. His two references are worth looking at. They are:
[Treadmill motor to drill drive conversion](http://shdesigns.org/Craftsman-12x36/treadmill.shtml) and
[similar on you tube](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-a-Treadmill-DC-Drive-Motor-and-PWM-Speed-Contr/)